# How do I shut down a win10 box exactly like it shuts down using start menu "button," but via task scheduler?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, power-management, scheduled-tasks

**Preface:**
This box locks up when it goes to sleep (requires 5sec hard kill to power off and reboot), so the intent is to disable sleep, yet shutdown via task scheduler after set idle time.

**Details:**
This MSwin10 box shuts down fully when using the start menu, however, the command line `shutdown /s` and Powershell's `stop-computer` commands both result in a half state where fans and lights continue to run.

I have sleep, hibernate, & fast start disabled as evidenced by `cmd\powerfg /A` and group policy output.  The scheduled task works, in that it runs the requested commands, but it is running commands that only yield a half off state.

Comment: does the /f(orce) switch on shutdown do anything?

Comment: I suggest troubleshooting why the machine locks up on sleep (or on wake) rather than trying to work around it. Event Viewer tell you anything?

Comment: @dlatikay /f yields no change in shutdown behavior, not does the timer

Comment: @Harv I take this to be a hardware issue, as I don't find any errors in event viewer during this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I've just now created a quick python script to do this.

```
from pyautogui import keyDown, press, keyUp 

keyDown('winleft') 
press('x') 
keyUp('winleft')
press('u')
press('u')
```

The above script will send "Win+X", followed by two presses of the "U" key which, if you try that right now, will shut down your computer. Then, you can go to Task Scheduler and do the following:

1. Create a Basic Task
2. Set the action for this task to Start a program
3. Fill out the "Action" menu as follows:

[image]

All other information about the task can be decided by you, but this will execute the script exactly as if you'd asked the computer to shutdown via the start menu.

**Notes:**

1. The main idea here is to send keystrokes. I wouldn't be surprised if you could do this via powershell (which would avoid the need to download python), but I often see users write that SuperUser is not a script writing service, so I didn't want to dedicate any more than about a minute writing a script.
2. You asked for a method which shuts down the computer

> exactly like it shuts down using the start menu "button"

But you should note that this presents a problem in that, if you have programs running which Windows will not shut down, the computer will hang until you tell it to "Shut down anyway"

**Versions:**

I have tested this and it works for me using:

python          version 3.8.2

pyautogui       version 0.9.50

Windows 10 Home version 1909

Comment: No need for Python for this, you can do the same with VBScript and PowerShell using SendKeys.

Comment: @postanote As I said in the notes at the bottom of my post, I just wrote what I was easiest for me to write.

Comment: Understood, but I jumped in due to your "Result in a half state where fans and lights continue to run." comment. I don't particularly care to hit that Windows Key, jus to do a shutdown, lock, hibernate, etc. especially in RDP sessions. Hence the reason I have shortcut defaults for all of those on all my RDP targets, and my local workstations. It just keeps this sort of thing a single click away. The sendkeys stuff just requires more code. I do use it, just not for this use case.

Comment: python may be it, as sendkeys doesn't seem to handle windows key

Comment: Not true. See my update

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead... (see the shutdown.exe help for an explanation of the switches)

```
shutdown.exe /s /f /t 00
```

I have shortcuts (pinned to my taskbar for all the Power Options) and scripts that do this, and I've never countered this...

> "Result in a half state where fans and lights continue to run."

As per my SendKeys comment, see these:

- [SendKeys Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=netcore-3.1)
- [SendKeys.Send(String) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=netcore-3.1)
- [WshShell.SendKeys](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)

So, automating say Notepad...

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
& "$env:WinDir\Notepad.exe"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("~Name:{TAB}$env:UserName~")
```

... similar can be down for virtually any interactive user command.

***Update***

```
# Activating the Windows Key
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^{ESC}')
```

Retested on

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).Version

# Results
<#
10.0.19041
#>
```

Comment: Looks like send keys doesn't handle windows key.

Comment: Not true. I show this kind of operation in all classes I delver. Just do what I show in the update.